# How do you make munin stop sending alerts for smart exit statuses?

Tags: munin

Since I installed munin and enabled alerts, it has been intermittently sending me this for four of my hard drives:

> WARNINGs: smartctl_exit_status is 4.00 (outside range [:1]).

The [munin documentation](http://gallery.munin-monitoring.org/node.d/smart_.html) says:

> The `ignoreexit` parameter can be useful to exclude some bits in smartctl exit code, which is a bit mask described in its main page, from consideration.

So I added the following to `/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node`:

`[smart_sdg;smart_sdh;smart_sdi;smart_sdj]
env.ignoreexit 4`

(Note that this corresponds with the four drives sending the alerts.)

Alas, the alerts keep coming. I can't make them stop and I don't understand why. Is my config location wrong? Am I doing the configuration wrong? Why isn't this working? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had an old version of Munin and it doesn't support the `env.ignoreexit` parameters. I grabbed the latest version of the plugin from Munin's repository and it seems to work.

This was a fun exploration. I wish Munin threw errors when you gave it configurations it didn't recognize, but alas.